# How to Customize jQuery DateTimePicker to select time using drop downs

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker

I need to use jQuery DateTimeDropDown to select both Date and Time. For selecting time by default it gives scrolling kind of control. Instead of that, I want to use dropdown lists for selecting time.

Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Thanks